# Drawing a rectangle around mouse drag Pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, opengl, pyglet

I'm trying to create a square that forms around the drag of a mouse (like the one that appears when dragging on the desktop, for example.) THis is the code I've tried:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import mouse

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [x, y, dx, y, dx, dy, x, dy]))

pyglet.app.run()
```

However, it's not working, and I can't see why. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as there hasn't been an answer, this is how I solved the problem:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import mouse

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    pass

@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [x, y, x-dx, y, x-dx, y-dy, x, y-dy]))
    print x, y, dx, y, dx, dy, x, dy
pyglet.app.run()
```

Now I just need to work out how to destroy the rectangles...

Answer (score 6):

I started with your solution and improved it a bit. The rectangle artifacting problem is fixed by adding an on_draw function, and in that function you clear the window and then re-draw every object. Pyglet (OpenGL) uses double-buffering, so this works a lot faster than it sounds.

```
import pyglet

# rectangle class

class Rect:

  def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
    self.set(x, y, w, h)

  def draw(self):
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, self._quad)

  def set(self, x=None, y=None, w=None, h=None):
    self._x = self._x if x is None else x
    self._y = self._y if y is None else y
    self._w = self._w if w is None else w
    self._h = self._h if h is None else h
    self._quad = ('v2f', (self._x, self._y,
                          self._x + self._w, self._y,
                          self._x + self._w, self._y + self._h,
                          self._x, self._y + self._h))

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"Rect(x={self._x}, y={self._y}, w={self._w}, h={self._h})"

# main function

def main():
  r1 = Rect(10, 10, 100, 100)
  window = pyglet.window.Window()

  @window.event
  def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    r1.draw()

  @window.event
  def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    r1.set(x=x, y=y)
    print(r1)

  @window.event
  def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    r1.set(x=x, y=y)
    print(r1)

  pyglet.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: When I run your script, I get:

return f"Rect(x={self._x}, y={self._y}, w={self._w}, h={self._h})"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

is this a python 2 vs python 3 thing? If I comment it, the script runs properly.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how you are passing your class rectangle to the window. That is, how does pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, self._quad) knows it has to draw the rectangle in window = pyglet.window.Window(). (Cus it's the active window?)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes
from pyglet.shapes import BorderedRectangle
from pyglet.window import key

def init():
    display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()

    # for screen in display.get_screens():
    #     print(screen)

    screen = display.get_screens()[0]
    config = pyglet.gl.Config(double_buffer=True)

    return pyglet.window.Window(screen = screen, config=config, resizable=True)

window = init()
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
box_list = []
drawing_box = False
rectangle = None
box_position = [0,0,0,0]
X = 0
Y = 1
W = 2
H = 3


def getSelected(x, y):
    pass

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
    pyglet.gl.glFlush()

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    print(f"window resized width: {width} and height: {height}")

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    print(f"key: {chr(symbol)} pressed with modifier: {modifiers}")
    return True

@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    global drawing_box
    global rectangle

    #print(f"this keys: {chr(symbol)} and modifiers: {modifiers} are no longer pressed")
    if (drawing_box == True):
        drawing_box = False
        if box_position[W] < 0:
            box_position[X] = box_position[X] + box_position[W]
            box_position[W] = -box_position[W]

        if box_position[H] < 0:
            box_position[Y] = box_position[Y] + box_position[H]
            box_position[H] = -box_position[H]

        rectangle = shapes.BorderedRectangle(box_position[0], box_position[1], box_position[2], box_position[3],
                                             border=3, color=(200, 200, 200),
                                             border_color=(255, 255, 255), batch=batch)
        rectangle.opacity = 100
        box_list.append(rectangle)
        rectangle = None

@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    #print(f"button : {button} at ({x},{y}) modifiers: {modifiers}")
    global drawing_box
    global box_position

    if(modifiers == key.MOD_SHIFT):
        drawing_box = True
        box_position[0] = x
        box_position[1] = y
    else:
        selected = getSelected(x, y)

import inspect

@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    #print(f"mouse dragging at x: {x}, y: {y} button: {buttons} and modifier: {modifiers} are pressed")
    global drawing_box
    global box_position
    global rectangle

    if drawing_box == True:
        box_position[2] = x-box_position[0]
        box_position[3] = y -box_position[1]
        rectangle = shapes.BorderedRectangle(box_position[0], box_position[1], box_position[2], box_position[3],
                                             border=3,color=(200,200,200),border_color=(255, 255, 255), batch=batch)
        rectangle.opacity = 100


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyglet.app.run()




#attrs = vars(rectangle)
# {'kids': 0, 'name': 'Dog', 'color': 'Spotted', 'age': 10, 'legs': 2, 'smell': 'Alot'}
# now dump this in some way or another
#print(', '.join("%s: %s" % item for item in attrs.items()))
#print(inspect.getmembers(BorderedRectangle, predicate=inspect.isfunction))
```